# How to enable dump_stack() in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I am trying to build a new syscall that calls dump_stack(). How do I enable dump_stack() in the first place? Which config files and macros do i have to change?

Comment: What stacks are you going to dump?

Comment: https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Enabling_Stack_Dumping_in_Linux_Kernel#Using_dump_stack.28.29

Comment: thanks for the link. had a dependency issue that wouldn't let me error make menuconfig.